# use mouse drag to change the width of a rectangle?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I got this code that helps me draw a rectangle from another SO answer, I'd like to be able to drag the left and right sides of the rectangle to adjust the width of the rectangle, make the rectangle behave in a way similar to how you crop an image on most photo editing software, where you draw the initial area but you have the possibility to adjust the width afterwards to get the crop you want.
the code I have so far:

```
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()
        self.show()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        br = QBrush(QColor(100, 10, 10, 40))  
        qp.setBrush(br)   
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))       

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        # print(f"press begin {self.begin}")
        # print(f"press end   {self.end}")
        self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        #self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        #self.update()
        print(f"begin {self.begin}")
        print(f"end   {self.end}")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this on a PyQt forum, courtesy of a man by the name of `Salem Bream`, he answered my question, I thought I'd share it with the SO community.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


FREE_STATE = 1
BUILDING_SQUARE = 2
BEGIN_SIDE_EDIT = 3
END_SIDE_EDIT = 4


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30, 30, 600, 400)
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.end = QPoint()

        self.state = FREE_STATE

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        br = QBrush(QColor(100, 10, 10, 40))
        qp.setBrush(br)
        qp.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if not self.begin.isNull() and not self.end.isNull():
            p = event.pos()
            y1, y2 = sorted([self.begin.y(), self.end.y()])
            if y1 <= p.y() <= y2:
                # 3 resolution, more easy to pick than 1px
                if abs(self.begin.x() - p.x()) <= 3:
                    self.state = BEGIN_SIDE_EDIT
                    return
                elif abs(self.end.x() - p.x()) <= 3:
                    self.state = END_SIDE_EDIT
                    return
        self.state = BUILDING_SQUARE

        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()

    def applye_event(self, event):

        if self.state == BUILDING_SQUARE:
            self.end = event.pos()
        elif self.state == BEGIN_SIDE_EDIT:
            self.begin.setX(event.x())
        elif self.state == END_SIDE_EDIT:
            self.end.setX(event.x())

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.applye_event(event)
        self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.applye_event(event)
        self.state = FREE_STATE


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWidget()
    window.show()
    app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```